# Count number of times values in a range are found in an array in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a range, call it `B2:Z2` with numbers in some cells, others are blank.
And I have an array, call it `BA2:BG10`, every cell has a number.

I am trying to count if a number in my range appears in my range. It should only count each number in the range once, even if it appears multiple times in the range.

Example:

```
Range: |_|2|_|_|5|_|_|_|_|11|_|_|_|_|15|_|

Array: |1 |3 |5 |6 |41|
       |11|16|15|1 |44|
       |9 |11|49|43|1 |

Result: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution, but haven't figured out how to do it without a helper row. Posting this in case it puts you or someone else on the right track.

Here I use

```
=--OR(B2=$B$7:$F$9)
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and copied across to the right. This flags hits as 1's, which can then be summed to give the correct answer which is 3 in your example.

[image]